# Target a nested div coming from an external component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using an imported component which I can't change.

This component has a lot of nested divs.

Somewhere deep in these divs, I need to add a **bottom margin** to it.

Via Chrome DevTools, I am able to add the margin in one of the divs and achieve the

margin I want. But unable to get it to work when I try to add my css into my scss file.

How can I do this?

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* This component is not in my control. I can't modify this component*/}
      <ImportedComponent/> 
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I see it in Chrome DevTools, the CSS is something like this.

If I were to add a margin style near the aCssClass or within the block of aCssClass via Chrome,

I get the margin I need. But as said, able to achieve in Chrome DevTools, but not via my scss file.

```
<div class="my-own-class">

    <!-- This is all coming from ImportedComponent, each div has some css class -->
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="aCssClass anotherClass"> <!-- i want to be able to add my margin here, able to do it but only via Chrome dev tools-->
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some data
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

These are the styles I tried which makes no difference.

```
.my-own-class {
  margin-bottom : 1em;
}

.my-own-class > div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-bottom : 22px;
}

.my-own-class body .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

body .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

body > .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.my-own-class .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.my-own-class > .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

Screenshot

At the highlighted portion, I added margin-bottom 10px under body .sc_marginRight_0 on the right panel which works.

[image]

Comment: I guess the class name changes constantly? Or is it constant ?

Comment: @Zerowiel It is constant.

Comment: .my-own-class .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
} 
Should work, can you provide us a codepen or else ?

Comment: What happens if you style your class ? Is the css applied ?

Comment: Add a color style,  to see if anything is getting applied. Use the dev tools to see what is being applied and what is being over-written. Are there default styles for the component? `.my-own-class .aCssClass` [works with the code you have provided](https://jsfiddle.net/vg2yh0mo/)

Comment: @Zerowiel Sorry struggling with a code pen. Added a screenshot of the actual structure. Unsure if it helps illustrate the problem.

Comment: @JonP Added a background to color to all above CSS and none has any effect. There are no default styles, none pertaining to margins. Added a screenshot on the actual thing. Unsure if it helps meanwhile trying to code pen it but unable to with the amount of stuff going on in it.

Comment: The problem here might be your css not being imported ^^'

Comment: @Zerowiel The css is imported fine. There are other styles in the same file which is working.

Comment: The basics are correct. There is something else going on outside what you have presented us. Double-check that `myClass` matches in the HTML and CSS. Set something else with `myClass` and make sure that works. What do you see when you inspect the element after applying your class? Do yo see any reference to it? Ideally we need to see code that replicates the problem.

Comment: @JonP Notice all the above CSS I written, comes up under sources in Chrome but that is it. They are not in use within any div. Unlike the other CSS like an example sc_padding_10 class in above screenshot which is in use within the divs.

Comment: That tells me the class has not been applied correctly, check spelling of class name etc. Use `.my-own-class  { color:red; }` . Inspect your parent `.my-own-class` element using dev tools. Has the class been applied at that level? Any chance this is encapsulated in an iFrame along the way?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's just a specificity problem, try adding !important and it will work just fine.

```
.my-own-class .aCssClass {
  margin-bottom: 22px !important;
}
```

Comment: Added !important to all the above css I tried, makes no diff unfortunately.

Comment: NO! solve the specificity problem instead. See : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: i think if he made .my-own-class unique it won't cause a problem ?